# How to change screen resolution within android kernel

Tags: android

What I want to do is change the screen resolution in the kernel of a hardware similar phone (has similar hardware but different screen size) so ROMs and Kernels can be swapped between the different phones.  Is this possible?  Where would I find and change this data?

Answer (score 0):

On some systems, you can change the screen resolution in uboot when it starts the kernel.